# wchar functions under Android NDK

Tags: android-ndk

Here is my simplified code:

```
static void WriteToFile(const wchar_t* msg) {
  FILE* f = fopen("/sdcard/mytest.txt", "w");
  fprintf(f, "%ls\n", msg);
  fclose(f);
```

}

```
// Somewhere else in the code
const wchar_t* msg = L"Hello world";
WriteToFile(msg);
```

Using `%ls` to format a wchar string seems to work fine in Windows and Ubuntu. However, on Android, it writes only the first character `H` in the file.

I even tried to convert wchar to mbs:

```
char buf[100];
wcstombs(buf, msg, 100);
```

However, `buf` still ends up having just one character `H` in it.

I have a feeling that it is happening because wchar is four bytes long on Android. However, I would think the NDK must be aware of this.

How do I fix this? Regards.

Comment: You need [CrystaX NDK](https://www.crystax.net/android/ndk). Also, there seems to be a bug in printf specific to Android-21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using wcstombs, etc., use APIs from libiconv (https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/). You may have to build libiconv library for Android.